# Fix bash bug on Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: bash, ubuntu-13.10

I tried to fix the bash bug on Ubuntu using

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install bash
```

but it failed.

I guess something is wrong with the source.list file.

Anyone know which source I should add to the file?

Comment: You need to post the exact console log, not a vague description of approximately what happened. Please remove the guesswork for us.

Comment: @allquixotic There's nothing to guess here. 13.10 is EOL.

Comment: Oh, right! Totally forgot about that. Wasn't thinking 13.10 would be EOL already O_O

Answer (score 2):

Your Ubuntu distribution is no longer supported. It will not receive any further updates. This is called End of Life. Basically your system is and will always be unsecured.

Upgrade your installation to 14.04, which will continue to receive updates until April 2019.

Or manually compile the latest version of Bash, but I wouldn't recommend that unless you're a little experienced with these things.

Answer (score 0):

I have ubuntu 13.04 and 13.10 and i update the bash using the trusty repository, only change the distribution name in /etc/apt/source.list.

Next execute apt-get uptade
and finally execute apt-get install --only-upgrade bash

I make the next script to reply to my other servers:

```
#!/bin/bash
DISTRIB=`lsb_release -cs`
sudo cp /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.backup
if grep -q 'old-releases' /etc/apt/sources.list; then
    echo "old-releases found."
    sudo sed -i 's/old-releases/us.archive/g' /etc/apt/sources.list
fi
echo "Upgrading bash..."
sudo sed -i 's/'$DISTRIB'/trusty/g' /etc/apt/sources.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --only-upgrade bash
sudo cp /etc/apt/sources.list.backup /etc/apt/sources.list
sudo apt-get update
echo "Upgrade bash finish."
```

You can visit my [blog for detailed instruction in spanish](https://oscarif.wordpress.com/2014/10/01/actualizar-bash-en-ubuntu-13-04-o-13-10/)